# Locate not find on no loPartialKey

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, tclientdataset

I'm using Delphi XE2 and I'm having problems with TClientDataset.Locate method. It will only locate if `loPartialKey` is passed as param. In other case, it will not find the record, even though the record definitely exists.  Here is a code snippet:

```
result := lSysEq.Locate('IDIV;CODE_EQ',VarArrayOf([aDiv,aEqCode]),[]));
```

Where `aDiv` and `aEqCode` are string types and `lSysEq` is the `TClientDataset`.  I don't believe I'm doing anything wrong and I've broken down to the most basic application. Still I cannot locate the proper record.

Comment: You are going to need to provide some more information and some sample data that fails. Don't assume that the lookup is wrong. If it matches on a partial key locate, then assume there are extra chars on the end of CODE_EQ. For example, if you could have untrimmed data that came out of a fixed length database field. You could be overlooking spaces that are hard to see at the end, and they would cause a non-partial match to fail.

Comment: Have you tried adding loCaseInsensitive option?

Comment: What is the record you can't find?